# Customize connection entity crm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, connection

My current client has added a number of custom fields to the connection entity in dynamics CCRM 2013. They are trying to model a hierarchical relationship between companies, contacts and some custom entities. I've recommended they abandon this approach and use a custom "intersection" or "associative" entity. A sort of "roll your own" many to many.
Is anyone aware of any formal Microsoft documentation advising against customization of the connection object? I have recommended they read this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531171.aspx#BKMK_Connections) which suggests connections should be used to model informal relationships. Thanks!

Comment: Not strictly answering your question but:
One thing to be aware of with Connection records is that they're created in   pairs, and CRM reverses the fields to create a mirrored pair.
However, for custom fields - these aren't reversed (because CRM wouldn't know to reverse them).

Comment: That's a good point, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your advice is correct.

The Connection entity was designed to easily create "low profile" relationships between various records giving users the ability to freely associate data. Formal database relationships (1:n, n:m) are a different story.

I am not aware of limitations regarding the customization of the Connection entity. Microsoft made it customizable for a reason, so I think adding attributes and relationships to it is in itself a sound idea.

Of course, a customizer can extend the CRM data model to the point that it becomes way too complex and inefficient, but that's a risk that is applicable for any information system.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know why one would customize the connection entity, but you are right, it is customizable for a reason. My main concern was the incorrect use of connections to model formal relationships however, so it seems I'm on the right track here. Going to mark this as the answer